# Passing compiler flags via make argument rather than Makefile

Tags: makefile, compiler-flags

Is it possible to add certain compiler flags to all the compiler calls (all the .cpp files) via `make` argument rather than Makefile? If it is possible, then how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. You can pass to `make` an operand of the form `VARIABLE=value` which defines `make` variable `VARIABLE` to have `value`, overriding the content of `VARIABLE` defined in your Makefile. Consult the documentation of your `make` implementation for more details. Notice that this may work differently when using `:=` assignment in GNU make.